# Combining two overall effects in the same forest plot with (meta)

Tags: r, r-forestplot

I'm using the (meta) package in R to analyze a meta-analysis. I have two random-effects models, both rma objects. One model, x1, is all the studies included in the analysis and x2 is the same model but with a few studies excluded. I am trying to create a forest plot with all of the studies using the forest function, but I can't figure out how to get it to display the overall effects including confidence intervals, of both x1 and x2 together on the same forest plot. I've searched everywhere online and can't seem to find an appropriate answer.

Does anyone know of a solution or have any ideas?

Comment: This is what the `addpoly()` function is for. You will find examples in the docs here: https://wviechtb.github.io/metafor/reference/addpoly.rma.html

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need - does this also work for the (meta) package? I just realized I'm using meta and not metafor, apologies for the confusion

Comment: No, `addpoly()` doesn't work together with forest plots created with the meta package.

Comment: Is there a way to implement this using the meta package?

Comment: I don't know. I am the author of the metafor package, so I know quite well how to do things with that package, but meta was written by @guido-schwarzer so maybe he can chime in.